# on focus is not calculating dynamic items

Tags: jquery

I am using jquery on focus for some calculation.. Please find html and jquery code...

```
<div>
<input type="text" name="items[0]cost" class="currency">
<input type="text" name ="items[0]quantity" class="qu">
<input type="text" class="tam">
</div>
```

I have even added an option to generate these fields dynamically, and its working fine, and i am having problem with following code...

```
$(function(){
    $('#items').on('blur', '.qu', function(){
        var $parent = $(this).closest('tr');
        var $quantity = $(this).val();
        var $currency = $('.currency', $parent).val();
        var $totalamount = $('.tam', $parent);
        var $amount = parseFloat($currency*$quantity);
        $totalamount.val($amount);
    });
});
```

Add Item

```
var i = 1;
    $('#add-item').on('click', function(){
        i++;
        var $itemrow = '<div id="'+i+'"><input type="text" name="items['+i+']cost" class="currency"> <input type="text" name ="items['+i+']quantity" class="qu"> <input type="text" class="tam"><button class="remove-item">X</button></div>';
        $('#items tr:last').after($itemrow);
    });

    $('#items').on('click', '.remove-item', function(e){
        $(this).closest("tr").remove();
    });
```

Its doing calculation fine for available fields but not working on dynamically added fields, please suggest, what am i missing? thanks.

Comment: can you show us a fiddle?

Comment: How do you create the fields dynamically? with document.createElement('input') ? or with JQuery ?

Comment: can you also provide the code of generating dynamic fields?

Comment: @Learning added, question edited

Comment: @daguru jquery code added

Comment: okay so you binding the on blur event on pageload of javascript then creating the items, that why your code is not working for dynamically generated item.

Answer (score 0):

If you dynamically create additional elements, they won't by default get the event handlers assigned to the originally added elements. When dynamically adding the elements, you need to make sure that you add the event handler to them.

So, in your add item code, you need to use this:

```
var i = 1;
$('#add-item').on('click', function(){
    i++;
    var $itemrow = $('<div id="'+i+'"><input type="text" name="items['+i+']cost" class="currency"> <input type="text" name ="items['+i+']quantity" class="qu"> <input type="text" class="tam"><button class="remove-item">X</button></div>');
    $itemrow.on('blur', '.qu', eventHandlerFunction);
    $('#items tr:last').after($itemrow);
});

$('#items').on('click', '.remove-item', function(e){
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();
});
```

And then make your code for defining the initial blur event handler:

```
function eventHandlerFunction(){
    var $parent = $(this).closest('tr');
    var $quantity = $(this).val();
    var $currency = $('.currency', $parent).val();
    var $totalamount = $('.tam', $parent);
    var $amount = parseFloat($currency*$quantity);
    $totalamount.val($amount);
}
$(function(){
    $('#items').on('blur', '.qu', eventHandlerFunction);
});
```

That will add the `eventHandlerFunction` to the `blur` event on your inputs.

Comment: thanks but this line `$itemrow.children.on('blur', '.qu', eventHandlerFunction);` stopped Add Item function...

Comment: I've made a small change to it, does this fix it? I've removed the `.children` from that line.

Answer (score 0):

As you have created your element dynamically so event will not be attached with you input field(as event assigned at pageload)

So you can use `onblur` attribute with `textbox` as :

```
var i = 1;
    $('#add-item').on('click', function(){
        i++;
        var $itemrow = '<div id="'+i+'"><input type="text" name="items['+i+']cost" class="currency"> <input type="text" name ="items['+i+']quantity" class="qu" onblur="calculate(this)"> <input type="text" class="tam"><button class="remove-item">X</button></div>';
        $('#items tr:last').after($itemrow);
    });

    $('#items').on('click', '.remove-item', function(e){
        $(this).closest("tr").remove();
    });
```

and

```
function calculate($this)
{
var $parent = $($this).closest('tr');
        var $quantity = $this.value;
        var $currency = $('.currency', $parent).val();
        var $totalamount = $('.tam', $parent);
        var $amount = parseFloat($currency*$quantity);
        $totalamount.val($amount);
}
```

**EDIT :**

Use delegation for live events as

```
$(document).on('click', '.qu', function(){
//your function here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I recreated your example by guessing the actual HTML that you have, and I only changed the way rows were being inserted to

`$('<tr></tr>').html($itemrow).appendTo('#items tbody');`

I also changed the HTML on $itemrow so it reflects the content that a table row should have.

The fields seemed to be calculated without a problem.

Here's the working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/EfrainReyes/hkmR2/2/